# Can AWS Cognito be used for mobile social login without web views?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

According to the [Amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/ios/#launch-social-web-ui-sign-in) during the Cognito social login, the user gets redirected to a web view.

Can the social authentication flow, with Cognito be done in a way, so that instead of a web browser the user uses an already installed Google/Facebook app to login?

Comment: I'm stuck on same issue. if you have found solutions please share here